# Like pageflakes (Incremental Page Display OR Lazy Load)?

Tags: asp.net

I need to know how to load user control after the page is completely loaded 
Incremental Page Display OR Lazy Load concept
typically like Pageflakes ?

Answer (score 1):

This is called Ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp

To address your comment below, here is a (VERY SIMPLE) example of such a thing, using the jQuery library. http://jquery.com/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#content").load("/myajaxpage.htm");
 });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This would download the myajaxpage.htm page after loading, and put the contents into the div with the id "content".

Comment: Many thanks, but what I need to know is how to load user control after the page is loaded